# How can I make my navbar item responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navbar

the elements that contain the "buttons" divine in my code are not responsive continuously up to 1204 pixels, their size shrinks and the texts become two lines, not one. How can I solve this problem? The snippet code does not work properly, since I have set the navbar as min-width: 1240px for now, please check it in your own code editor.

```css
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

a{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size:16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

li{
    list-style-type: none;
}

#nav-wrap{
    width: 100%;
    height: 98px;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
}

.container{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1366px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0rem 0.8rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1240px) {
    .main-wrap{
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .list .list-item{
        width: 750px;
        height: 98px;
    }

    .list > ul{
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }
      
      .list > ul > li{
          padding-left:4rem;
    
      }
      
      .list > ul > li > a{
          padding: 2rem 0rem;
          font-weight: 400;
          height: 100%;
      }
      
      .list > ul > li > a:hover{
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font-weight: 500;
      }
      
      .buttons{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        font-weight: 500;
        border-left: 1px solid gray;
        height: 98px;
        padding-left: 4rem;
    }
    
    .buttons a{
      padding: 12px 15px;
      background-color: #F47825;
    }
    .buttons .account{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding-left: 3rem;
        color:#1F6099;
    }
    
    .buttons .account i{
        padding-right: 1rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>CarMax</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='global.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='responsive.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
   <nav id="nav-wrap">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="main-wrap">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="https://www.greenmountainenergy.com/wp-content/themes/gmec-bones/library/images/gme-logo-spring2017-refresh.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>
           <div class="list">
        <ul class="list-item">
               <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Plans and Services</a>
            <ul>
                <a href=""> <span class="yav">RESIDENTAL</span></a>
                <li><a href="">Go Local Solar</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Solar with Green Mountain Driver</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Solar All Nighter for EVs</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Renewable Rewards® Buyback Plan</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Get a Quote on Home Solar Panels</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="space"><bold>View All Your Electricity Plans
                </bold></a></li> 
                <a href=""> <span>COMMERCIAL</span></a>
                <li><a href="">Electricity for Small Business</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Commercial Solar Power</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Solar Buyback Program</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Channel Partners</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><bold>Get A Quote for Your Business
                </bold></a></li>
              </li>
            </ul>  
               <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Why Go Green?</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-item">
                    <a href=""> <span class="yav">RESIDENTAL</span></a>
                    <li><a href="">Go Local Solar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Solar with Green Mountain Driver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Solar All Nighter for EVs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Renewable Rewards® Buyback Plan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Get a Quote on Home Solar Panels</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="space"><bold>View All Your Electricity Plans
                    </bold></a></li> 
                    <a href=""> <span>COMMERCIAL</span></a>
                    <li><a href="">Electricity for Small Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Commercial Solar Power</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Solar Buyback Program</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Channel Partners</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><bold>Get A Quote for Your Business
                    </bold></a></li>
                  </li>
                </ul>  
            </li>
               <li class="dropdown"><a href="">About Us</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-item2">
                    <a href=""> <span class="yav">RESIDENTAL</span></a>
                    <li><a href="">Go Local Solar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Solar with Green Mountain Driver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Solar All Nighter for EVs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Renewable Rewards® Buyback Plan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Get a Quote on Home Solar Panels</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="space"><bold>View All Your Electricity Plans
                    </bold></a></li> 
                    <a href=""> <span>COMMERCIAL</span></a>
                    <li><a href="">Electricity for Small Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Commercial Solar Power</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Solar Buyback Program</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Channel Partners</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><bold>Get A Quote for Your Business
                    </bold></a></li>
                  </li>
                </ul>  
            </li>
               <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Customer Service</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-item3">
                    <a href=""> <span class="yav">RESIDENTAL</span></a>
                    <li><a href="">Go Local Solar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Solar with Green Mountain Driver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Solar All Nighter for EVs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Renewable Rewards® Buyback Plan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Get a Quote on Home Solar Panels</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" class="space"><bold>View All Your Electricity Plans
                    </bold></a></li> 
                    <a href=""> <span>COMMERCIAL</span></a>
                    <li><a href="">Electricity for Small Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Commercial Solar Power</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Solar Buyback Program</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Channel Partners</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><bold>Get A Quote for Your Business
                    </bold></a></li>
                  </li>
                </ul>  
            </li>
        </ul>
           </div>
           <div class="buttons">
               <a href="">View Plans</a>
               <div class="account">
                <i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i>
                <span>My Account</span>
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
       </div>
   </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp)

Comment: The link is not made with the navbar flexbox system, but thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem, the buttons not appears because you don't set the .main-wrap that wrapping the list and buttons.

I try to add the setting like this, and the buttons appearing

```
.main-wrap{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: Dude, check the code thoroughly, these codes are already written.

Comment: Sorry, I mean you can write it before the media query. Because you write it only on devices with a minimum width of 1240px. If you want to see buttons on devices that are less than 1240px you have to write them in global css as well.